# set camera raw filter as an adjustment layer - photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter

Is it possible to apply the camera raw filter (filters > camera raw filter) in a PSD as an adjustment layer rather than a 'set once' filter ?

Comment: I think the short answer is 'no', but if you can expand your question to explain why you might want this then we might be able to suggest a workaround. Also, have a look at this tutorial if you haven't already seen it: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/camera-raw-filter.html

Comment: Thanks, ive found a way to do it if you make the photo layer a smart layer, then you can create a camera raw filter as an adjustable / toggle layer ontop.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, convert your background to smart object and then put camera raw on it. It appears as a smart filter.